# How would I go about finding the offset of points on a shape from a set point?

Tags: excel, coordinates, reshape, shapes

So say I have a shape and it starts at the coordinate of 0,0. How would I go about finding the offset of the rest of the points on that shape? Is there an easy way to do this with a program? I've heard that this can be done in excel or with Python but after looking into this I have yet to find anything concrete to aid me.

[I'd like to find out the offset of each point from the 0,0 point (example image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPJk4.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Vertices property of the Shape object. The corner you want won't be at 0,0, but you can adjust.

```
Public Sub FindShapeCoords()
    
    Dim shp As Shape
    
    Set shp = Sheet1.Shapes(1)
    
    Debug.Print "x", shp.Vertices(1, 1) - shp.Vertices(2, 1)
    Debug.Print "y", shp.Vertices(1, 2) - shp.Vertices(2, 2)
    
End Sub
```